# jQuery event handlers does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var imgadd = $("<img/>",{
        src:"../img/Koala.jpg",
        alt:"Koala",
        id:"koala",
        click:function(){$(this).css("opacity","50%");},
        mouseenter:function(){$(this).css("hight","200px")}
    })
    $("body").append(imgadd);
```

why does it  not  work？I got a little pizzled...

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: What is the error, post the Error line :)... it is helpful to understand the problem very clearly for all dev people.

Comment: I think you need to do that after document.ready

Comment: You need to spell hight height, but the opacity does not work for some reason

Comment: @Pekka the image does not change...

Comment: In addition to @mplungjan `opacity` is not `%` but a value in the range of `0` to `1`

Comment: problem is solved and thank you all.The author makes mistake and I follow it.

Comment: @mplungjan: I can see what you did there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is structurally correct, the issue is that you made two typo's.

1. `opacity` takes a value between 0 and 1, not a percentage.
2. `height` was misspelled.

Here's code that will work:

```
var imgadd = $("<img/>",{
    src:"http://idordt.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/wk-koala.jpg",
    alt:"Koala",
    id:"koala",
    click:function(){$(this).css("opacity","0.5");},
    mouseenter:function(){$(this).css("height","200px")}
})
$("body").append(imgadd);
```

And a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredcrowe/3fvht8s2/

Comment: This. This is the only correct answer. Well caught.

Answer (score 2):

Change the values either 0 to 1

```js
var imgadd = $("<img/>",{
   src:"http://idordt.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/wk-koala.jpg",
   alt:"Koala",
   id:"koala",
   click:function(){alert("hello");$(this).css("opacity","0.2");},
   mouseenter:function(){$(this).css("height","200px")}
  })
  $("body").append(imgadd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll let you implement my changes :)))